# Is there a way to disable the offset replication in MirrorMaker 2?

Tags: apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I do not have access to the "source" cluster for creation any topics besides the ones explicitly granted. I wanted to use the MirrorMaker2 for replication between the source and target, but failing with properly configuring the source cluster.

```
[2021-08-15 13:48:51,601] ERROR [Worker clientId=connect-2, groupId=<XXX>] Uncaught exception in herder work thread, exiting:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:324)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [mm2-offsets.target.internal]
[2021-08-15 13:48:56,394] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=source-mm2] Herder stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:738)
```

Is there a way to disable the offset replication in MirrorMaker 2?

Answer (score 2):

I did this deploying MM2 in Kafka connect and with the following property:

> ```
> "sync.group.offsets.enabled": false
> ```

Even with that, it's necessary to create an internal topic, in this case, mm2-offsets.target.internal, but now with [KIP-716](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-716%3A+Allow+configuring+the+location+of+the+offset-syncs+topic+with+MirrorMaker2) (Apache 3.0), you can do it in the target cluster, so it isn't necessary to create a topic in the source cluster:

> ```
> "offset-syncs.topic.location": "target"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

- Launch a Kafka Connect with RESTful API
- Create a [MirrorSourceConnector](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/mirror/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/mirror/MirrorSourceConnector.java) only